# For a manual evaluation of a definite integral

Tags: reference-request, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, integration

I note that Mathematica could yield the identity
$$\int_0^1\frac{\log(1+x^2(x-1)/2)}{x^2(x-1)}dx=\frac{\pi(\pi-4)-12\log^22+24\log2}{16}.\tag{1}\label{1}$$
But I don't know how Mathematica got this.

**Question.** How to prove \eqref{1} manually?

Your comments are welcome!

Comment: If you just ask for the indefinite integral, you'll get an expression in terms of elementary functions and PolyLog[2,.], which you can readily differentiate and check ... which, aside from answering the question, might also give some insight into why the indefinite integral ends up being what it is ...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

With Mathematica, one can actually find an antiderivative $F=G+H$ of the function $f$, where
$$f(x):=\frac{\ln(1+x^2(x-1) /2)}{x^2(x-1)},$$
$$G(x):=-\text{Li}_2\left(\frac{1-x}{2}\right)-\frac{1}{2}
   \text{Li}_2\left(-(x-1)^2\right)+\text{Li}_2(-x)+\text{Li}_2\left(\left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{i}{2}\right) x\right)+\text{Li}_2\left(\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{i}{2}\right) x\right),$$
\begin{gather}
    H(x):=\frac{\left(x \ln \left(\frac{x-1}{x}\right)+1\right) \ln \left(\frac{1}{2} (x-1)
   x^2+1\right)}{x}+\ln (x+1) \\ 
   +\ln (x) \left(\ln
   \left(1-\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{i}{2}\right) x\right)+\ln
   \left(1-\left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{i}{2}\right) x\right)+\ln (x+1)\right) \\ 
   -\ln (x-1)
   \left(\ln (i x+(1-i))+\ln \left(\frac{1}{2} ((1+i)-i x)
   (x+1)\right)\right) \\ 
   -\frac{1}{2} \ln ((x-2) x+2)+\tan ^{-1}(1-x). 
\end{gather}
This can be verified by differentiation, since $\text{Li}'_2(x)=-\ln(1-x)/x$.

The desired result now follows because
$$G(0)=\frac{\ln ^2(2)}{2}-\frac{\pi ^2}{24},\quad G(1)=\frac{1}{48} \left(\pi ^2-12 \ln ^2(2)\right),$$
$$\lim_{x\to0}H(x)=(\pi - \ln4)/4,\quad \lim_{x\to1}H(x)=\ln2.$$

---

The indefinite integral of $f$ can be found "more manually" as follows. Integrate $f$ by parts, to get an integrand of the form $R(x)+R_0(x)\ln x+R_1(x)\ln(1-x)$ instead of $f(x)=\dfrac{\ln(1+x^2(x-1) /2)}{\cdots}$, where $R(x),R_0(x),R_1(x)$ are certain rational expressions. Use then partial fraction decomposition (involving certain complex constants) to reduce the integrand to ones of the form $\frac{\ln u}{u+a}$, and note that
$$\int \frac{\ln u}{u+a}\,du=
\text{Li}_2\left(-\frac{u}{a}\right)+\ln(u) \ln\left(\frac{a+u}{a}\right)+C.$$

Comment: Hoping that you do not mind, I elaborated in my miserable answer using your more than nice suggestion.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici : I have upvoted your answer. I think it is better to try to avoid negative adjectives in characterizing one's work, including one's own.

Answer (score 3):

Being lazy, I also computed the antiderivative.

The problem is that Mathematica does not evaluate the result at the bounds since it faces indeterminate forms.

However,  series expansions give
$$I(1)=\left(\frac{1}{48} \pi  (43 \pi -24)+\frac{\log ^2(2)}{4}+\log
   (2)+i \pi  \log (2)\right)+\frac{x-1}{2}+O\left((x-1)^2\right)$$
$$I(0)=\frac{1}{12} \left(-3 \pi +10 \pi ^2+6 \log (2) (-1+2 i \pi +2\log
   (2))\right)+\frac{x}{2}+O\left(x^2\right)$$ and then the result.

**Edit**

Using @Iosif Pinelis's suggestion at the end of his answer, integrating by parts lead to

$$\int\frac{\log(1+x^2(x-1)/2)}{x^2(x-1)}dx=\left(\frac{1}{x}+\log (1-x)-\log (x)\right) \log\left(\frac{1}{2} (x-1) x^2+1\right)-$$
$$\int\frac{x (3 x-2) \left(\frac{1}{x}+\log (1-x)-\log
   (x)\right)}{(x+1) \left(x^2-2 x+2\right)}\,dx$$ Using the bounds, the first term is $0$
$$I_1=\int_0^1\frac{3 x-2}{(x+1) \left(x^2-2 x+2\right)}\,dx=\int_0^1 \left(\frac{x}{x^2-2 x+2}-\frac{1}{x+1}\right)\,dx$$
$$I_1=\frac{1}{4} (\pi -6 \log (2))$$ For the remaining
$$\frac{x(3 x-2)}{(x+1) \left(x^2-2 x+2\right)}=\frac{1}{x-(1-i)}+\frac{1}{x+1}+\frac{1}{x-(1+i)}$$ leads to simple integrals and
$$\int\frac{x (3 x-2) \left(\log (1-x)-\log
   (x)\right)}{(x+1) \left(x^2-2 x+2\right)}\,dx=\frac{3 \log ^2(2)}{4}-\frac{\pi ^2}{16}$$ and then the result.

I suppose that this is the simplest manual approach.